# server is not receiving body object from webservice call of restkit

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20, restkit-0.24.x

I want to send put request using restkit putobject and receive the response as 200 and string from the server, but server is giving me 400 and saying not receiving body.
Request is
request: https://myserver.com/api/v1/f1//update
body = "somevalue"
Response is 200
"somevalue"

for this i am having restkit implment
request https://myserver.com/api/v1
path f1//update

here is the code

```
RKObjectMapping *responseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ModelUpdate class]];
 [responseMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"status"]];

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor =
[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:responseMapping
                                             method:RKRequestMethodPUT
                                        pathPattern:path
                                            keyPath:nil
                                        statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];
*objectPath=path;
RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:[responseMapping inverseMapping]   objectClass:[ModelUpdate class] rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodAny];

[rkObjectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
[rkObjectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
rkObjectManager.requestSerializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;
[rkObjectManager putObject:someObj path:path parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

    id updateField = mappingResult.array;
    [sDFWebInterface->m_DFWebInterfaceData receiveResponse:updateField forRequestNo:requestNo error:nil];
    NSLog(@"Success");

} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error from server in Put Request");
    [sDFWebInterface HandleServerAPIError:requestNo :error];
}];
  /////Modelupdate class
 @interface ModelUpdate : NSObject
 @property(nonatomic,strong)NSString* status;// : 

  @end
```

Comment: So what is the server receiving as the body and what are you expecting it to receive? What is `someObj`?

Comment: someobj basically a string object someobj="newvalue"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request descriptor specifies `objectClass:[ModelUpdate class]`, so it will only be used when you supply an object of class `ModelUpdate`.

`someobj basically a string object someobj="new value"` doesn't match the spec so the request won't be processed. You should see an error about that in the log.

If you just want to send a simple string and get a simple string in the response then you don't really need RestKit. If you want to process the string in and out of a `ModelUpdate` then you need to supply an appropriate instance.

Comment: is it possible with rest kit or not if we want to putobject as string object and receive a string object. can we use [NSNull null] ?

Comment: A simple string on its own isn't valid JSON, so no. If you created your own serialisation, but that's more effort than just making the request...

Comment: I went ahead with your suggestion and directly using AFNetworking Http client in this situation where we are not getting JSON response.